# How can I create a list of a combination of attributes in API.AI (Dialogflow)

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a requirement where I want to accept a list of 2 attributes from API.AI, for example, the user can say any of the following:

add 2 oranges and 3 bananas 2 my cart

add 2 oranges 3 bananas and 5 apples to my cart

So it should send a list of the combination of count and fruit-name to my application. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlecFenichel - This is actually a valid question for Dialogflow; the example given requires usage of an advanced feature (Composite Entities) and the resulting answer will be useful to other developers. It doesn't involve writing any code. See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dan Imrie-Situnayake . I had tried this approach. However, the issue here is that we need to provide all the synonyms when we define the entity "fruit". In a broader scenario , say for an application that allows you to add groceries, there will be thousands of values the "fruit" can take, it does not seem scalable. Do we have any other way of doing it without defining synonyms for the "fruit"?

Comment: @Alec Fenichel . As mentioned by Dan, this is actually a question on how to use dialogflow composite entities for the said use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with [Composite Entities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities#developer_composite).

First, create an entity that lists all of the fruit and their synonyms (let's call it `fruit`).

Then create a composite entity (let's call it `number-of-fruit`) that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of number-of-fruit entity]

You just need one value, without synonyms, and it should contain the two parameters you wish to collect:

- `@sys.number-integer:number` (the `@sys.number-integer` part represents the System Entity for integer, the `:number` part is the name we'll give this parameter)
- `@fruit:fruit` (the `@fruit` part is the name of our fruit entity, the `:fruit` part is the name we'll give this parameter)

Now, when you add an example containing items in this format to an intent, you'll see that your new composite entity is detected:

[image]

However, the occurrences in the example are currently being treated as two separate parameters, not a list. To treat these entities as a list as opposed to two discrete items, select the second highlighted example and click the item that corresponds to the first parameter (in the screenshot it's the one with the blue text saying `number-of-fruit`):

[image]

Now, you'll see that the parameters section indicates that this parameter is a list:

[image]

Once you save and train, you can test that this works for an arbitrary length list via the console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan. I had tried this approach. However, the issue here is that we need to provide all the synonyms when we define the entity "fruit". In a broader scenario , say for an application that allows you to add groceries, there will be thousands of values the "fruit" can take, it does not seem scalable. Do we have any other way of doing it without defining synonyms for the "fruit"?

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you have a second question. Could you mark your original question as answered and create another question? If you link it here I can answer it ASAP.

Comment: i have the same problem except i am looking to distinguish 2 lists, i am building a converter application which converts from one type to another type, one type = list of values, another type = list of values, any ideas how this can be achieved, thanks in advance

Comment: @SandeepMaller write a cron job that gets a list of all food items and updates the entities every x hours, that is what i am doing in my case, use the API provided by dialogflow to programmatically post entities

Comment: Just found out you were that guy on the tutorial I have watched. Please include this in your YT videos. Thanks! :)

Comment: @DanielSitunayake I have created a new post to figure out how we can create a shoppinglist without the need of defining every product itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380665/dialogflow-composite-entities-with-random-text