# Adding and removing items from a cart in Dialogflow

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I am prototyping a Food Ordering app using [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/)(Chatbot maker) and got stuck with this problem. Technically, I want to persist the gathered data from an `Intent` after the user decided to "add more items to their order" and satisfies all the required parameters, which are, `(itemName, quantity, [variants], [sauceType], ...)`.

The chat bot should be able to handle a request which consist of multiple items with their corresponding quantities but I am not sure if it's possible to model a data wherein it consist an array of `Entities` so, my first thought was to use a persistent `Fulfillment` using session-based Webhook with our custom Web Service, like for example: `foodorder/api/order/123/items/add` and `123` being the Session Id. But this approach requires more work and the generated model can be difficult to translate in Dialoflow Console.

The second solution comes into my mind, is to leverage the Intent property called `Action and Parameters` where we mark the `Entity` as `List`, but using this approach, the quantity doesn't get attached to the item itself.

My question is, how can I be able to model a data using Dialogflow that resembles something like below:

```
{
    "givenName": "Dummy User",
    "order": [
        {
            "itemName": "Burger",
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "itemName": "6 piece Chicken Nuggets",
            "quantity": 1,
            "sauceType": "Tangy Barbeque"
        },
        {
            "itemName": "Coke",
            "quantity": 1,
            "size": "Small"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I was looking for was **Composite Entities** and mark it as a list.

The detailed answer can be found on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166123/2304737