# Dialogflow composite entities with random text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a shopping list Voice UI bot with Dialogflow.

I ran into some issues with linking the number and the product together. I found 1 solution here [How can I create a list of a combination of attributes in API.AI (Dialogflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148736/how-can-i-create-a-list-of-a-combination-of-attributes-in-api-ai-dialogflow)

The problem with this solution is that we have to specify all the products available.

How can I create a shopping list in dialogflow without having to define every product in another entity.