# Dialogflow Multi-Item Recognition

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, nlu

I am pretty new to Dialogflow, and I am building this food ordering chatbot.

The users can say

```
I want a chicken burrito.
```

or

```
I want two chicken burrito, one beef burger, two coca-cola, one french fries.
```

but the problem I am facing now is that Dialogflow can only match up to three items, e.g. `I want two chicken burrito, one beef burger, two coca-cola`. The recognition will just fail completely if there are more than three items to be matched in one sentence.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148736) Stackoverflow solution answer you initial question?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem as I am already using this approach. And it doesn't match more than three items.

Comment: What is your Dialogflow version (ES/CX)? Can you share more context about the intent configuration? How did you define entities for products and counts?